How can I store namespaces on a table and change *able_type column data type with integer in Laravel polymorphic relation?
I have three different model in my Laravel project; Convoy, User, Driver. Driver is a different model than User because of they can not authenticate. Whatever, there is also one more model: Address.
I am storing address values on the addresses table, Address model. Columns are given below;
addresses : addressable_type (int), addressable_id (int) ...
There is also one more model named as Type, it stores type of everything in the project. For example it stores authorization types (Super User, User, Admin, etc...), eloquent model types which is given under Models\ path (App\Models\User, App\Models\Driver, etc...), payment types etc...
I think you got it what am I gonna ask to you but let's continue. If you figure out, I did not set the type of addresses.addressable_type as varchar(255). Normally, polymorphed model can read App\Models\* format but instead of this I want to store id of eloquent model from types.id table.
addressable_type    | 10 // this refers to `types`.`id`
addressable_id      | 1
country             | 225
state               | 2175
city                | 108155
address             | NULL
status              | 1
created_at          | 2024-08-31 14:50:13
updated_at          | 2024-08-31 14:50:13

id                  | 10
type                | App\Models\Convoy // so this is record in the types table
label               | 2
created_at          | 2024-08-31 14:50:12
updated_at          | 2024-08-31 14:50:12

Convoy.php given below;
class Convoy extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function address() : MorphOne
    {
        return $this->morphOne(Address::class, 'addressable');
    }
}

Address.php given below;
class Address extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function addressable() : MorphTo
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    public function status() : BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Status::class);
    }
}

HomeController.php given below;
public function convoys() : View
    {
        $test = Convoy::with('address')->find(6);
        dd($test);
        return view('convoys', compact('convoys'));
    }

Result;
App\Models\Convoy {#1228 ▼ // app/Http/Controllers/HomeController.php:50
  ...
  #relations: array:1 [▼
    "address" => null
  ]
  ...
}

I can't get any kind of address.

Are you having to follow a specific model structure or is this your own setup?
I would recommend that you store all of your users using the user model and then set up another that would manage their permissions/roles.

When I fetch a Convoy record with given code $test = Convoy::with('address')->find(6); it brings id = 6 Convoy record. I want it's address data from addresses table. And "App\Models\Convoy" string is stored in types table and that record has an id ( for ex. 15 ). I want to say to polymorphic system "do not look the App\Models\Convoy on the addresses table, look for 15". So I want to morph looking for type id on types table.

Just out of curiosity, why would you not want to use the type and type_id in the polymorphic relationship? They would work as a compound key so you wouldn't need to use the id column to fetch the data

you can update the AppServiceProvider and add this
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation;

Relation::morphMap([
        10 => App\Models\Convoy::class,
        11 => App\Models\User::class,
        12 => App\Models\Driver::class,
    ]);


This is not worked. When I say on Convoy.php;
public function address() { return $this->morphOne(Address::class, 'addressable'); } it looks for where addressable_type = 'App\Models\Convoy' but I want to change this query with looking firstly id (ex 15) of 'App\Models\Convoy' value in types table, secondly replacing this id value on the query. where addressable_type = 15

I have update the answer please check it

So thanks Hamdallah, you are the best!

I would recommend that you use a polymorphic relationship as it is intended. You would have the following as your polymorphic relationship:
<?php
class Address extends Model
{
    public function parent(): MorphTo
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}

I would then further recommend you then use a trait to attach this to any models that will have an address associated to them (this will help prevent duplicated code)
<?php
trait HasAddress {
    public function address(): MorphOne
    {
        return $this->morphOne(Address::class);
    }
}

Then inside your Convoy, User, Driver or anything else that will have an address you can simply add the following into the beginning of it.
use HasAddress;

